# Set featured image for multiple posts

Tags: post-thumbnails

Does anyone know how I can set an image as featured image for multiple posts.

I have posts in a seri that I would like to use the same image as featured image.

bulk edit doesn't have featured image in there though.

Comment: An image uploaded to WP Media Library stays available for multiple posts. Even though you Featured the image once for a post, you can use the same image as a featured image for almost unlimited posts. Edit each one and then add feature image - browse the media library and make the image as featured image. What's stopping you?

Comment: @MayeenulIslam what I mean to ask was how to bulk edit those posts and set featured image for all at once.

Answer (score 1):

You could hook into the `publish_post` action, check if a featured image has been set, and if not, assign the image you want as the featured image.

The [publish_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/publish_post) Codex page has a nice example about changing a post after it has been published.

Answer (score 1):

we can use  `echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page_ID, 'thumbnail');` 
in php tag, where is the page/post id the page/post from where we want to display the featured image. Here is a link for it [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your function.php

```
update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $thumbnail_id);
```

You can also create a function to do this, with as custom fields of the "main" post.

```
function setSameThumbnails($post_id) {
    // I assume that your custom field will be something like "31,64,43" for posts ids
    $posts = get_post_meta($post_id, 'same_thumbnail', true);
    if($posts)
    {
        $posts = explode($posts, ',');
        if(is_array($posts))
        {
            foreach($posts as $post)
            {
                update_post_meta($post, '_thumbnail_id', get_post_thumbnail_id($post_id));
            }           
        }
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'setSameThumbnails');
```